# Creating a Python Deployment Package for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am attempting to upload my Python 3.6.1 code to AWS to be able to run it on Lambda.

Not being very familiar with the process, I am sort of lost. The python script that I want to upload will be making external API calls to GitLab to pull repository information that will be written to a text file and saved to an S3 bucket.

To do this, I have to import the requests module. I have read online that if you are importing any other modules besides boto3, that you must re-install them via pip to the root of your deployment package folder, then put your Python code in that folder, and then zip that folder and upload that to Lambda.

I have also seen other posts suggesting that one will have to change the 'Handler' in the configuration section of the Lambda settings for the function in regards to whatever their 'Main()' function is called within their Python code?

However, all of the documentation that I have read online regarding this has been vague and I haven't had any luck. I tried going through the AWS documentation on this and followed the instructions, but I wasn't able to get it configured correctly.

I have tried it numerous times but I keep getting the error:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambdaUpload'"
}

(lambdaUpload is my file name for the .py file)

If anyone is familiar with how to create these "Python Deployment Packages" for Python scripts that are utilizing third party modules, and could either explain how to do this or route me to some clear documentation on this then that would be greatly appreciated.

I know its probably not too difficult once one knows how to do this, but sometimes figuring out how to do it the first time is the hardest part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code to upload the function should be something like:

```
boto3.client("lambda").create_function(
    FunctionName="functionName",
    Runtime="python3.6",
    Role="arn:......",
    Handler='lambdaUpload.lambda_handler',
    Code={
        'ZipFile': open(self.project_zip_file, "rb").read()
    }
)
```

The most important is the parameter `Handler`. It is **"name of your .py file (without extension)"."main function to be called"**.

So, in this case, in your `.zip` file you must have a file called `lambdaUpload.py` in the root folder with a code like:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   print("AWS Event ID: " + context.aws_request_id)
   print("Event Body: " + json.dumps(event))

   return "Hi"
```